# Android Live microphone sound Streaming out

Tags: android, audio

I would like to stream microphone.
And use http server on android so that
user just go http://xxxx.xxx.xx.xxx/xxx.wav can listen to what I say?
How can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

I would try to develop a small HTTP server which serves an FLV stream.

You can take [ipcamera-for-android](http://code.google.com/p/ipcamera-for-android/) as an example. This app serves a FLV video stream however you could reuse the server and the FLV encoder part.

As FLV supports PCM streams you can simply copy the buffer of the microphone to your stream.

#### Another variant

You can encode the microphone stream using the built-in `MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC`. Afterwards you can simply serve the AAC as a stream to your client.

Comment: I study ipcamera-for-android long time ago.But first performance is not that good and also some code doing transcoding to FLV will crash the apps.But i have no idea to do so.

Comment: Actually i want to stream to wowza. But ffmpeg in tablet got poor performance. So I just put ffmpeg in server and taking picture as jpeg and use ffmpeg to transcode to flv and stream to wowza. So I just need a song stream

Comment: the song stream idea is come from this app https://market.android.com/details?id=com.pas.webcam&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5wYXMud2ViY2FtIl0.

Comment: how to make aac as stream?can u give me some hints??